# Check previous row in datetime, if time is greater than a certain value, place in a group and take its duration in seconds (R, dplyr, lubridate)

Tags: r, loops, dplyr, lubridate

I have a dataset, df:   (the dataset contains over 4000 rows)

```
  DATEB

  9/9/2019 7:51:58 PM
  9/9/2019 7:51:59 PM
  9/9/2019 7:51:59 PM
  9/9/2019 7:52:00 PM
  9/9/2019 7:52:01 PM
  9/9/2019 7:52:01 PM
  9/9/2019 7:52:02 PM
  9/9/2019 7:52:03 PM
  9/9/2019 7:54:00 PM
  9/9/2019 7:54:02 PM
  9/10/2019 8:00:00PM
```

I wish to place in groups (if the times are not within 10 seconds of the previous row) and then take the duration of the newly formed group.

Desired output:

```
Group   Duration

 a       5 sec
 b       2 sec
 c       0 sec




 dput:


  structure(list(DATEB = structure(c(2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 
  7L, 8L, 9L, 1L), .Label = c("      9/10/2019 8:00:00 PM", "      9/9/2019 7:51:58 PM", 
  "      9/9/2019 7:51:59 PM", "      9/9/2019 7:52:00 PM", "      9/9/2019 7:52:01 PM", 
  "      9/9/2019 7:52:02 PM", "      9/9/2019 7:52:03 PM", "      9/9/2019 7:54:00 PM", 
  "      9/9/2019 7:54:02 PM"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
  -11L))
```

I have tried the code below, which works well, except, I am wanting the units in seconds only. The code below gives units of minutes and seconds.

```
  library(dplyr)
  library(lubridate)


  df2 <- mutate(df,
          DATEB = lubridate::mdy_hms(DATEB))

 df2$time_since_last_row <- df2$DATEB - lag(df2$DATEB)
 df2$time_since_last_row[[1]] <- 0 # replace the first NA
 df2$group_10s <- 0

 for ( i in 2:nrow(df2))
   {
 if(df2$time_since_last_row[[i]]>seconds(10))
 df2$group_10s[[i]] <-  df2$group_10s[[i-1]] +1 
 else 
 df2$group_10s[[i]] <-  df2$group_10s[[i-1]]
      }





 df3 <- group_by(df2,
            group_10s) %>%
   summarise(volume_in_group=n(),
   min_DATEB=min(DATEB),
   max_DATEB=max(DATEB),
   group_duration = max_DATEB - min_DATEB)



   #nirgrahamuk-R community
```

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: you should look at the `%--%` operator of lubridate to make intervals (for `group_duration`) and `time_length(x, unit = "second")` to get it's length in seconds

Comment: Ok thank you, I will research. I was wanting to incorporate units = "secs" within this code above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I would do:

```
gap_threshold <- 10
df %>%
  mutate(DATEB = lubridate::mdy_hms(DATEB), 
         gap = c(0, diff(DATEB))) %>% 
  group_by(grp = cumsum(gap > gap_threshold)) %>% 
  summarise(begin = min(DATEB), end = max(DATEB), 
            duration = difftime(end, begin, units = "secs"))
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 3 x 4
>     grp begin               end                 duration
>   <int> <dttm>              <dttm>              <drtn>  
> 1     0 2019-09-09 19:51:58 2019-09-09 19:52:03 5 secs  
> 2     1 2019-09-09 19:54:00 2019-09-09 19:54:02 2 secs  
> 3     2 2019-09-10 20:00:00 2019-09-10 20:00:00 0 secs
> ```

Note that there are more columns in the output than requested just for demonstration.

Whenever the gap between two subsequent rows is greater than the given `gap_threshold` the group count `grp` is advanced by one. Finally, `min()` and `max()` are taken for each group and the duration is computed from these.

Comment: Ok thank you I will try, and the thresh is 10 seconds right?

Comment: You can set `gap_threshold` to whatever value seems appropriate for your problem.

Answer (score 1):

In fact I did something similar before. You can modify your last block with:

```
df3 <- group_by(df2, group_10s) %>%
  summarise(
    volume_in_group=n(),
    min_DATEB=min(DATEB),
    max_DATEB=max(DATEB),
    group_duration = as.numeric(max_DATEB - min_DATEB, units = "secs")
  )
```

Comment: ok I will try, is this creating a newly formed group if the time from previous row exceeds 10 seconds?

Comment: No it simply does the calculation. I am making a more complete answer.

Comment: Ok thank you! I just need to change a column that contains mixed units to seconds. (My current column contains minutes and seconds; I only want seconds)